# What's the relationship between java thread and system thread

Tags: java, android, linux, ipc

Recently, I researched the `Handler` class in Android System. In my opinion, the `Handler` mechanism is that the `Thread` runs a dead loop and retrieves messages from the queue repeatedly in that dead loop, it then sends the message to target handler.

But when there aren't message in queue, the thread have to be waited or blocked for a specified time, this can reduce CPU time. My understanding is that in order to wait or block the `Thread` for a specified time, it uses the linux epoll function to wait specified time in native layer. It then uses a linux pipe to wake the thread when there are messages in queue.

So my confusion is **why Android systems use Linux process communication functions(IPC) to control the Java `Thread`** to wait or wake up? And **what's the relationship between Java `Thread` and system thread or linux thread**?

**In other words,what I really want to know is why android use linux ipc function to control the java threads to implement so-called Handler which is used to send message between java threads.**

Here is the [relevant code from the Android platform](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/cd92588/core/java/android/os/Looper.java)

```
public static void loop() {
        final Looper me = myLooper();
        if (me == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No Looper; Looper.prepare() wasn't called on this thread.");
        }
        final MessageQueue queue = me.mQueue;

        // Make sure the identity of this thread is that of the local process,
        // and keep track of what that identity token actually is.
        Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
        final long ident = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();

        for (;;) {
            Message msg = queue.next(); // might block
            if (msg == null) {
                // No message indicates that the message queue is quitting.
                return;
            }

            // This must be in a local variable, in case a UI event sets the logger
            Printer logging = me.mLogging;
            if (logging != null) {
                logging.println(">>>>> Dispatching to " + msg.target + " " +
                        msg.callback + ": " + msg.what);
            }

            msg.target.dispatchMessage(msg);

            if (logging != null) {
                logging.println("<<<<< Finished to " + msg.target + " " + msg.callback);
            }

            // Make sure that during the course of dispatching the
            // identity of the thread wasn't corrupted.
            final long newIdent = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
            if (ident != newIdent) {
                Log.wtf(TAG, "Thread identity changed from 0x"
                        + Long.toHexString(ident) + " to 0x"
                        + Long.toHexString(newIdent) + " while dispatching to "
                        + msg.target.getClass().getName() + " "
                        + msg.callback + " what=" + msg.what);
            }

            msg.recycle();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why all the downvotes?  Looks like a perfectly valid question to me.  Have a +1 to cancel some of them out.

Comment: @Simon,thanks for your support.

Comment: @Simon the down votes were are a sign this question is hard to understand. If you think that it's a good question then it helps to edit the question so that other's can see that. Just commenting doesn't (always) do the trick.

Comment: I really want to know what's the relationship between the thread in jvm and linux thread or system thread and what's the corresponding to java thread in linux system?Why the Android can use linux IPC and epoll to control java thread to be waited or blocked in native by JNI.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your question, my curiosity lead me to [this](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/binder-communication-mechanism-of-android-processes/) . And i believe there is a misunderstanding about the use of *Linux process communication functions(IPC)* to control the *Java Thread*.

I don't believe that i can explain it any better that the beautiful description given in the link.

[Communication Mechanism of Android Processes](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/binder-communication-mechanism-of-android-processes/)

Comment: The supplied article is so good that I understand the android platform.But what I really want to know is why android use linux ipc function to control the java threads to implement so-called Handler which is used to send message between java threads.

Comment: @KrystalJake I am not an android person, i just looked into it because of my curiosity. Hopefully we may get a better answer soon, lets give it some more time.